# Do you need to implement session tokens when using google autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

As I understand you can either use AutocompleteService or Autocomplete to get place predictions. For billing purposes I know that you need to provide a unique session token in AutocompleteService but do you have to do the same with Autocomplete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so there aren't any confusion, [**Place Autocomplete**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) is a feature of the Places library in the `Maps JavaScript API` in which is a `client-side` service. You may use this for apps that need user interaction. While [**Place Autocomplete Service**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) is a web service (`server-side`) that returns place predictions in response to an HTTP request which can instead be use to, say, batch processing.

Both can use session tokens but is `optional`. Places Autocomplete alone can be charged either by "per session" or "per character/request" as indicated in the [pricing sheet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/). According to this [optimization guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide#places):

- Autocomplete - Per Request: ideal for use cases where a single entry is enough, such as a mailing address form that a user fills out.
- Autocomplete - Per Session: Best used when multiple entries are required, such as searches for a hotel or restaurant.

Here are a few things to keep in mind:

- If using the Places Autocomplete widget (client-side), session tokens are automatically generated. If not using a widget, then you will have to manually generate a session token by manually calling [**new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken()**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#session_tokens).
- For generating a proper session token for web service use, refer [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#session_tokens).
- To keep a session token valid, read this [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/session-tokens).